# Custom error popup window background

Tags: android, popup, textview

Is there any way to set a custom layout for an error popup window in TextView:
[image: Valid XHTML].
In `textView.setError(String, Drawable)` we can set an error icon only.
`showError()` method in `TextView and ErrorPopup class are private, so I can't work with them.`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! Michael

**UPD:**
Thanks for comments, but as I understand it, the theme trick isn't applicable here:
(TextView 3384 line from android-10)

```
void fixDirection(boolean above) {
    mAbove = above;

    if (above) {
        mView.setBackgroundResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.popup_inline_error_above);
    } else {
        mView.setBackgroundResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.popup_inline_error);
    }
}
```

In android-15 com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_errorMessageBackground theme parameter is used, but it is internal.
Therefore I don't see any way to solve this problem, except writing my own error notificator ):

Comment: Maybe you can set a theme or style to it.

Comment: Maybe. In <code>TextView.showError()</code> com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_errorMessageBackground is used, but I can't find where I can change this parameter.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html for more info about themes, this attribute is probably private to textview but you can try to change via theming

Comment: You may want to use a subclass of EditText that implements its own custom error message layout. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15272453/1172181