# How to write style to error text of EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to write new custom style for my android application. I need to give style to errorText which appears after setting `setError` in `EditText`.

How can I customize style of it?

For example: I want to set its `background` white and `textColor`: Blue etc etc. in style.xml

[image]

Comment: Very open ended question. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Ok I m preparing Screenshot now

Comment: I doubt they will fix this bug but here you can see there is a solution with the support libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34780309/468360

Comment: how to change the black color of EditText error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is at the end and here is the screenshot:

[image: Styled error]

---

*Some Explanation*

You ***might*** be able to set the textcolor using the following line

```
yourEditText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='blue'>this is the error</font>"));
```

However, this might not be guaranteed.

---

According to the source code, this `Popup` that shows is of type `ErrorPopup` which is an internal class inside `TextView`. The content of this `Popup` is a single `TextView` inflated from `com.android.internal.R.layout.textview_hint`

```
final TextView err = (TextView) inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.textview_hint,
      null);
```

The background of this `Popup` depends on whether it should be placed above the anchor:

```
if (above) {
    mView.setBackgroundResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.popup_inline_error_above);
} else {
    mView.setBackgroundResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.popup_inline_error);
}
```

---

Since all the android resources used to create the popup are internal and ultimately hard-coded, your best shot would be to create your own error popup. This would be very easy and you wouldn't really be interfering with the normal `EditText` because the default popup is merely used to show the error, and, thus, creating your own would be fine.

---

**SOLUTION**

I have created it here: [WidgyWidgets](https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/WidgyWidgets)

Comment: @Eir the license is "you can all use it freely and bla bla bla"

Comment: this worked for me yourEditText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='blue'>this is the error</font>")); thanks

Comment: I replaced an edittext with your class, now nothing happens instead of error text shown and an red ! in the edittext.

Comment: it helped me i vote up..but how can i change red border line color as defined in question's image??

Comment: @perfection Get it and change it. You can find it on this page: http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html / search for popup_inline_error_am on the page

Comment: How can i change the color of text and background ?

Comment: playing with reflections is  like playing with fire :)  did  u hear about security manager?

Comment: I just git cloned your project @SherifelKhatib, unfortunately it does not compile in Android Studio.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think you can customize its style that way since the error popup [uses an internal style](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L3760):

```
mPopupInlineErrorBackgroundId = getResourceId(mPopupInlineErrorBackgroundId,
                    com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_errorMessageBackground);
mView.setBackgroundResource(mPopupInlineErrorBackgroundId);
```

However, you can set a [`Spanned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) and a custom error icon using the overloaded [`setError(CharSequence, Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

You can easily create a `Spanned` from HTML using [`fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

However, you still won't be able to set the popup background image :-(

Answer (score 10):

Please add it at the time of form validation if edit text field is blank.

```
            int ecolor = R.color.black; // whatever color you want
        String estring = "Please enter a valid email address";
        ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
        ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);

        edtEmail.requestFocus();
        edtEmail.setError(ssbuilder);
```

when you write in edit text, error sign automatic goes off

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the accepted answer but i don't like the proposed library

I think this is a bug in the Android framework and I filed a bug here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158590

EDIT:
the android design library TextInputLayout widget can be used to obtain a better error handling on EditText.

See how it looks like here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnQHb0fNtF8

And how to implement here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168

Comment: This is actually I know bug since forever https://plus.google.com/103362309911306712784/posts/bux1jG3t8HK

Answer (score 2):

follow this link to have a nice material design look of error message!
[materialdoc](http://www.materialdoc.com/user-input-errors/)
[image: screenshot]

**I see the link is not working anymore so here is how to do it:**
use `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ipAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                app:errorEnabled="true" >
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:width="200dp"
                    android:text="@{ethernetData.ipAddress}"
                    android:enabled="@{!ethernetData.ethernetAutoIp}"/>
```

and in code in `TextWatcher` (I use data binding) call `setError` on your `TextInputLayout`

```
binding.ipAddress.setError(your error);
```

this is how i did it:

```
binding.ipAddress.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(! Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher(editable.toString()).matches()) {
                binding.ipAddress.setError(your error string);
                IpAddressOK = false;
            }
            else{
                binding.ipAddress.setError(null);
                IpAddressOK = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine!

```
private fun setErrorOnSearchView(searchView: SearchView, errorMessage: 
String) {
val id = searchView.context
        .resources
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
val editText = searchView.find<EditText>(id)

val errorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red)
val fgcspan = ForegroundColorSpan(errorColor)
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder(errorMessage)
builder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, errorMessage.length, 0)
editText.error = builder
}
```

Comment: what kind of script is this?

Comment: This is KOTLIN.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any solution to edit error style, but I have created custom EditText with error popup. Hopefully, it will help:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.PopupWindow
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.StringRes

class ErrorEditText : EditText {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private var errorPopup: PopupWindow? = null

    fun showError(message: String) {
        showErrorPopup(message)
    }

    fun showError(@StringRes messageResId: Int) {
        showErrorPopup(context.getString(messageResId))
    }

    fun dismissError() {
        post {errorPopup?.dismiss() }
    }

      private fun showErrorPopup(message: String) {
        post {
            dismissError()
            val inflater = (context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater)
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_error, null, false)
            errorPopup =
                PopupWindow(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            errorPopup?.contentView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)?.text = message
            errorPopup?.showAsDropDown(this, 0, 10, Gravity.START)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use methods:
`showError(message: String)` or `showError(@StringRes messageResId: String)` to show the error and method `dismissError()` to hide it.

Keep in mind that pop-ups are bound with activity lifecycle if you are using multiple fragments to navigate through the app, remember about closing them when navigating.

Here is my edit_text_error layout used for popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="#fff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#E20000"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="Please enter a valid email address!" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you'd like to move popup to the end of EditText, please change last line in `showErrorPopup()` method to:
`errorPopup?.showAsDropDown(this, 0, 10, Gravity.END)`

You can manipulate the position of the popup by modifying gravity or x and y parameters of the `showAsDropDown(view: View, x: Int, y: Int, gravity: Gravity)` method

Comment: Not working. `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.name.views.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null`

Comment: It looks like you want to show it from the background thread. Try using those methods on the UI thread e.g. by using method: `runOnUiThread { showErrorPopup("Message") }` in your Activity/Fragment class.

Comment: When this error happens? Can you add more details or maybe code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: When the activity starts it crashes. More code? Dude I used your class.

Comment: `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public open fun postInvalidate()` This error also.

Comment: Well, due to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187673/problems-creating-a-popup-window-in-android-activity the popup cannot be showed too soon. I've edited the code to prevent this issue to throw an exception. Please try now.