# Change text edit error notification font in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, typeface

I know we can change edit text font by using `Typeface`. But what about errors we set for edit text?
Look at codes below:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ATaha.ttf");
private EditText mPasswordView;
mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
mPasswordView.setTypeface(font);
```

With this code I could only change edit text font but when I set error like this:

```
mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
```

The error notification font is android default font and didn't change by using type face. How can I change that?

Comment: I found a question that is similar to yours. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android

Comment: @Andrew But the only thing discussed there is color and no one mention changing font and there is no conclusion there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `SpannableString` to set the font:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(errorString);
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(font), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mPasswordView.setError(s);
```

A custom `Span` class that has a specific `Typeface` set:

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    private Typeface mTypeface;
    public TypefaceSpan(Typeface typeface) {
        mTypeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working for me on Android 4.4, but should work on all versions. Could you post your code for setting the error like this?

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot I'm using a custom `TypefaceSpan` class. I'll update my answer now..

Comment: It worked very good but is there any way change `SpannableString` without using new and creating new objects?

Comment: Not that I can think of, sorry. The overhead shouldn't be too much though, unless you have a form with 1000s of `EditTexts`, which would be crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't directly set a `Typeface` for error text, you can achieve it by setting an HTML string as a text inside it.

You can see HTML Tags supported by a `TextView` in [The CommonsBlog](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

We have `face` attribute for font, which means you can change the font-family.

```
mPasswordView.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font face='MONOSPACE'>Error font is MONOSPACE</font>"));
```

Comment: What about custom fonts in asserts folder? I need to use custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

By setting spannable string in error message or extend EditText and overrite your own error draw mechanism.