# setError in Edittext with RTL layout not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am facing issue with RTL layout for error view in `edittext`.
Error layout should be exact below in red Circle.
how to resolve this.??
thanks in advance
see the below screenshot:
[image: RTL screenshot]

below is the XML for edit linear layout

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/welcome_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_old_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_password_edit_1_drawable"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/login_password_edit_1_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/overpass_regular"
            android:hint="@string/old_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="12345678"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textHintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/h4"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_new_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_password_edit_1_drawable"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/login_password_edit_1_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/overpass_regular"
            android:hint="@string/new_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="12345678"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textHintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/h4"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_confirm_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/confirm_password_icon_drawable"
            android:drawablePadding="22.5dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/confirm_password_icon_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/overpass_regular"
            android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="12345678"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textHintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/h4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cannot understand actual and desired behaviors.

Comment: Probable solution to your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575825/textinputlayout-error-right-align

Comment: @azizbekian i want that error layout left side of the screen below the red circle with RTL language. its working fine with LTR language.

Comment: @buzzingsilently Thank you.. I already go to through that solution but as per design of the screen its not helpful for me. so please give some other suggestion for old method for setting error in edit text. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991884/4718406

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and for set error:

```
text_input_layout.setError("Error");
```