# How to give different color for inline error message and line color in textinputfieldeditext

Tags: android-layout, android-textinputedittext

I have `TextInputEditText` where I am showing inline error message also. Now the problem is whatever inline error message color I have given the same color is reflecting for the line also. How to give different colors for inline error message and line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set TextInputLayout error message colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709066/how-to-set-textinputlayout-error-message-colour)

Comment: No. I know how to change the inline error message color but my problem is which ever color I am using for inline error message same color is getting applied for the line which will be there for textinputeditext. I want different color for the line and for the error message how to achieve the same.

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I solved it by changing the color of colorAccent of my activity.