# How to reduce the space between EditText and its Error message?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to display error message below EditText. So, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33709380/513413).

This is my style:

```
<style name="FontLightItalic">
    <item name="fontPath">@string/font_light_italic</item>
</style>

<style name="errorAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_d64425</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And this is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/trip_description_input"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:hint="my hint"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorAppearance"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">

                        <com.company.styles.ClearableEditText . // It extends AppCompatEditText to add clear icon
                            android:id="@+id/trip_description"
                            style="@style/FontLightItalic"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_clear_business"
                            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear_business"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:text="@={userGroup.expenseDescription}"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/color_ccd6dd"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the result. How to reduce this gap?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this attribute from your `ClearableEditText`

> ```
> android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
> ```

Comment: Oh man, your answer shows I am blind :) Thanks for catching that.