# How to style separately hint and error text in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

In Android's widget TextInputLayout the style of active error and hint is identical, like this[image]

But when error is on, I want to see different color of hint (black, not red). How can I achieve this?

P.S. I've already tried to apply style programmatically with method .setHintTextAppearance(R.style.StyleName) but it didn't bring any effect

The code of TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextClient"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        android:hint="@string/login"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorAppearence" 
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
       app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Styles

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ErrorAppearence">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set TextInputLayout error message colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709066/how-to-set-textinputlayout-error-message-colour)

Comment: This seems awfully hard with the recent design libs. Any luck?