# Don't change textinputlayout hint color while setting error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing form using textinputlayout in Android

I don't want to change hint text color while setting error on textinputlayout as per below [image: textinput layout with error enabled]

```
textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true)
textInputLayout.setError("this field is required ")
```

// As of now this code is changing error message and hint color to red. But I don't want to change hint color to red. Only message color should be changed to red

I want to change error hint "nickname" to blue and error message to red color.

Comment: please share your code to proper understend

Comment: Hope this help you [How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout)

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

Use helper text styled as error text instead of error text.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextAppearance.TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="false"
    app:helperTextEnabled="true"
    app:helperText="Test error message"
    app:hint="your hint">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and made style that corresponds to your error style.

Comment: This is a good approch! If you need to take care of the Container to be read, like me, I just add a extra view to show the desirde red line. it's silly but working.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; It seems there's no way or workaround to do that.

Setting hint color to be different from error seems to be not possible to achieve with xml styling. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709066/how-to-set-textinputlayout-error-message-colour) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout) didn't work. No matter what combination I used, hint was always changed when error was set (to the error color).

So I did a bit of digging in the `TextInputLayout` code. It has hint color saved `defaultHintTextColor`, but this one is not used when state changes:

```
private void updateLabelState(boolean animate, boolean force) {
...
 } else if (errorShouldBeShown) { 
 collapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(indicatorViewController.getErrorViewTextColors());
...
```

The `collapsingTextHelper` seems to take responsibility for the hint drawing (it's the only one using hint color). However none on the properties I set after error happened worked `hintTextColor`, `setHintTextAppearance`, `defaultHintTextColor` (tried with `postDelayed`). In fact setting any of these can trigger `collapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(hintTextColor);` but then there's always update that triggers above code:

```
      if (defaultHintTextColor == null) {
        collapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(hintTextColor);
      }

      focusedTextColor = hintTextColor;

      if (editText != null) {
        updateLabelState(false);
      }
```

If you debug or check layout inspector you will not see a corresponding text view for the hint. The text is drawn by `collapsingTextHelper`so there's no even a way to get the hint view sadly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when an error is set on a TextInputLayout, the hint textColor is changed to the error color. To prevent this behavior, you can use a custom style for the TextInputLayout that overrides the hint textColor and the error textColor. It's a step-by-step process, follow me:

**First step:**

Create a new style in your styles.xml file that extends the default `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` style:

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/my_text_input_layout_hint_color</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@color/my_text_input_layout_error_color</item>
</style>
```

**Second step:**

Apply the custom style to your TextInputLayout in the layout file. Here's an example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_text_input_layout"
    style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="My Hint Text">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/my_text_input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Third step:**

In your code, when you want to set an error on the TextInputLayout, use the `setError()` function (and not `.error`) like this:

```
myTextInputLayout.setError("My Error Message", false)
```

Note that the second parameter in the `setError()` function is set to `false`. This way, the TextInputLayout doesn't change the hint textColor when an error is set. Instead, the error text color will be used for the error message.

Comment: There is no `setError` method on `TextInputLayout` that accepts a boolean parameter

Answer (score -1):

Set To Main Theme of App, It Works Only Highlight State Only

```
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try The Below Code It Works In Normal State

Change the theme of your TextInputLayout as given below

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ti_email"
        android:hint="@string/EmailAddress"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imEntremail"
        android:textColorHint="@color/view"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etentrEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:textColorHint="#B8B8B8"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In Styles Folder HintTextStyle Code  change the android:textColor code to change your floating label color

```
<style name="HintTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">26dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```